# Cardview doesn't have any affect on items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I'm trying to make my RecyclerView prettier, so I added a CardView. However, I don't see any changes when I ran the app, the UI looks like as if there's no CardView at all - there is not separation between the items. Can you please suggest what's wrong with my code here?

This is my list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/link_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@string/title_place_holder"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/link_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/link_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/link_summary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="@string/summary_place_holder"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is how I initialize my RecylerView:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mAdapter = new PostsAdapter(mPostList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        preparePostData();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a 1 line change in xml applied to the `CardView` element applying a margin.

```
android:layout_margin"@dimen/default_margin"
```

With your code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
    android:layout_margin"@dimen/default_margin">
```

And in the dimens resources file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="default_margin">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made changes in your code, please try below code

in place on

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
```

I've changed to below

```
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
app:cardElevation="6dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Just replace below layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com /apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
app:cardElevation="6dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/link_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/title_place_holder"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/link_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/link_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/link_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="@string/summary_place_holder"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` in CardView tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest application tag.

`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`